# Could not find poetry-1.2.2-linux.sha256sum file

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am trying to update my version of Poetry to 1.2.*, but when running `poetry self update` I get the error `Could not find poetry-1.2.2-linux.sha256sum file`... I can't figure out how to try and update Poetry to an earlier version for which hopefully the checksum exists.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are trying to update a Poetry that was installed with the `get-poetry.py` installer. This installer is deprecated for more than a year now. Updating via `poetry self update` is not possible for these installation. Uninstall Poetry and reinstall with the recommended installer.

More information are available at https://python-poetry.org/blog/announcing-poetry-1.2.0/

Answer (score 4):

The get-poetry.py has been even removed from repo, remove Poetry with the latest existing version :

curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/901bdf0491005f1b3db41947d0d938da6838ecb9/get-poetry.py | python3 - --uninstall

Then reinstall a fresh Poetry properly.

Comment: Thank you @ak-empiak for this updated answer: Following the 'accepted answer' by @finswimmer now fails for the reason you mention of `get-poetry.py` having been removed from the [top/HEAD of] the repo, but it's still there if you know where to look, as with your workaround. Coming back to using Poetry after a long gap this was very helpful (then continue to install Poetry with the remaining instructions in the the link @finswimmer posted in his answer)